# query to Extract from Json in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I've a json object in my postgres db, which looks like as given below

`{"Actor":[{"personName":"Shashi Kapoor","characterName":"Prem"},{"personName":"Sharmila Tagore","characterName":"Preeti"},{"personName":"Shatrughan Sinha","characterName":"Dr. Amar"]}`

**Edited** (from editor: left the original because it is an invalid json, in my edit I fixed it)

```
{  
   "Actor":[  
      {  
         "personName":"Shashi Kapoor",
         "characterName":"Prem"
      },
      {  
         "personName":"Sharmila Tagore",
         "characterName":"Preeti"
      },
      {  
         "personName":"Shatrughan Sinha",
         "characterName":"Dr. Amar"
      }
   ]
}
```

the name of the column be `xyz` and I've a corresponding `content_id`.

I need to retrieve `content_ids` that have `Actor & personName =  Sharmila Tagore`.

I tried many queries, among those these two where very possible query to get but still i didn't get.

```
SELECT content_id 
  FROM content_table 
 WHERE cast_and_crew #>> '{Actor,personName}' = '"C. R. Simha"'
```

.

```
SELECT cast_and_crew ->> 'content_id' AS content_id 
  FROM content_table 
 WHERE cast_and_crew ->> 'Actor' -> 'personName' = 'C. R. Simha'
```

Comment: There is actually an error in you json, is it a typo or is it really wrong?

Comment: Not sure If I understood your requirement. Post a desired result and also, show Us that you actually tried something first. If not, here is the [postgresql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) about json formats

Comment: I tried these two possible query but still not getting.. 

1) SELECT content_id FROM content_table WHERE cast_and_crew #>> '{Actor,personName}' = '"C. R. Simha"'

2)SELECT cast_and_crew ->> 'content_id' AS content_id FROM content_table WHERE  cast_and_crew ->> 'Actor' -> 'personName' = 'C. R. Simha'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to search in a nested jsonb array:

```
select content_id, value 
from content_table, 
lateral jsonb_array_elements(cast_and_crew->'Actor');

 content_id |                              value                              
------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
          1 | {"personName": "Shashi Kapoor", "characterName": "Prem"}
          1 | {"personName": "Sharmila Tagore", "characterName": "Preeti"}
          1 | {"personName": "Shatrughan Sinha", "characterName": "Dr. Amar"}
(3 rows)
```

Column `value` is of the type `jsonb` so you can use `->>` operator for it:

```
select content_id, value 
from content_table, 
lateral jsonb_array_elements(cast_and_crew->'Actor')
where value->>'personName' = 'Sharmila Tagore';

 content_id |                            value                             
------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
          1 | {"personName": "Sharmila Tagore", "characterName": "Preeti"}
(1 row)
```

Note, if you are using `json` (not `jsonb`) use `json_array_elements()` of course.